# Cannot find a way to create an application at Oracle Cloud Infrastructure in an identity domain without manual approach

Tags: oauth-2.0, terraform, devops, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I have managed to create an application for Oauth2 purposes in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure manually from web console in a domain. Anyway I cannot see a Terraform resource or an oci cli command in the documentation for it.
Does anybody managed to create it with an API call/oci cli command/Terraform?

I have tried to find a Terraform resource, oci cli command or API endpoint to create an application.
I expect to be able to create an application in a domain in OCI with code instead of manually creating the resource.